# H5 Tag showing different sizes between pages - Wordpress Theme Development

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I've been working on developing a Wordpress theme and can't figure this out. I zoom in 250% percent while on mobile, all the header text is the same on every page except for one. That one page it's showing is way larger than the rest, as if it's already being zoomed in. Any idea?

Code to zoom in for mobile.

```
.site-header h5 {
font-size: 250%;
letter-spacing: 2px;
color: #3b3a36;
font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
margin: 0;}
```

Div's I'm using on the same page.

```
.about-header {
width: 100%;}

.about {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
flex-flow: column wrap;}


.about1 {
width: 98%;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;}


.about2 {
width: 98%;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
padding: 10px;  
}

.about div:nth-of-type(1n+2) {
margin-left: 0px;
padding-bottom: 20px;   
flex: 1;}
```

The website I'm using to test my theme is http://rockstarfrenchie.com/ and the page that is showing a larger font size than any other header page is http://rockstarfrenchie.com/about/.

Please remember, I'm only having this issue on mobile, which means it has to do with me zooming in the text 250% somewhere but I can't figure this out.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the issue and it'll mean you'll need to make some changes to  your css, but at least things will be consistent across the board.

Your meta tag in the head of the document is wrong. You have:

```
<meta name="view port" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

`viewport` is one word. Change it to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: This explains a lot of why things where acting funny. Thanks!!